# OnOff Flipswitch to control lights

Tags: php, ajax

I want to control a led from a webpage with the help of on off flipswitch i found it in the net . I made a simple webpage with one flip switch that checks if GPIO x is High or Low and adapt this to the Flip switch , but i got no result , any help ?

My php script :

```
<?php
$read_gpio13 = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio read 13");
$red_checked = ($read_gpio13 == 1) ? "checked=\"\"" : "";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="Flip2.css">
   </head>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#myonoffswitch").change(function() {
         var isChecked = $("#myonoffswitch").is(":checked") ? 1:0; 
         if (isChecked){
         $.ajax({
                 url: 'red.php',
                 type: 'POST',
         });
           }
          else {
          $.ajax({
                 url: 'redoff.php',
                 type: 'POST',
         });
           }
       });
     });
  </script> 
 <form> 
 <div class="onoffswitch">
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" 
 id="myonoffswitch" <?php echo $red_checked; ?>>
 <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
</label>
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

red.php:

```
<?php
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g mode 13 out");
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 13 1");
?>
```

redoff.php:

```
<?php
// set to output
shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/gpio -g write 13 0");
?>
```

Comment: *"but i got no result "*. What does `var_dump($read_gpio13);` give?

Comment: try to use use exec('/command',$out);
shell_exec take only the first line. And read $out (it is an array).
You need user permission to exec the command.

Comment: that  give you the state of the gpio13   , i'm working on raspberry pi

Comment: @neoteknic , i tried it with simple on off button, and everything work fine , there's no prblm with permission , i  think the problem in the other part of the code ..

Comment: try my flipswitch, demo here  http://jsfiddle.net/ZqSVH/14/
code here https://github.com/delboy1978uk/flipswitch

Comment: thank you but i prefer that flipswitch , i already create my webpage and the design took me a lot of time , so if i change it i will waste time ( to know i'm beginner and i find a lot of difficulty to create/ modify  codes) ... so any help please ?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see ! Where is jquery ? :D you forget jquery ! Put this in head or before 
 the end of body !

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```